# How an I log the nth element in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an assignment to push these to the array then take one away. I'm having issue figuring out how to console log the third property of this array.

I tried a few different approaches but no dice. I'm new so I don't want to post exactly what I tried as we know it doesn't work or I wouldn't be here.

```js
var clothes = [];
clothes.push("Jorts");
clothes.push("White Tank top");
clothes.push("Sweat Pants");
clothes.push("Sandals and sox");
clothes.push("Affliction T shirt");
clothes.pop("Affliction T shirt");

console.log(clothes);
```

Comment: You *should* post what you tried to give us a better idea of where you're coming from; you might be very close and need just a bit of guidance.

Comment: The `.pop()` method does not need a parameter. It pops off (and returns) the last-pushed value.

Comment: It would also help if you would explain exactly what "wrong" means. Did *anything* happen? Were errors reported?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on the right track. To console log the third property of the array, you can use the following code:

```js
console.log(clothes[2]);
```

This will print "Sweat Pants" to the console, which is the third element in the array. Remember that array indices are zero-based, so the first element is at index 0, the second element is at index 1, and so on.

Answer (score -3):

The problem you have is that currentArray gets its value asynchronously, which means you are calling setAllEvents too soon. At that moment the allCallBack function has not yet been executed. That happens only after the current running code has completed (until call stack becomes emtpy), and the ajax request triggers the callback.

So you should call setAllEvents and any other code that depends on currentArray only when the Ajax call has completed.

NB: The reason that it works in the console is that by the time you request the value from the console, the ajax call has already returned the response.

Without having looked at the rest of your code, and any other problems that it might have, this solves the issue you have:

Comment: Did you mean to post this answer here? You are referencing variables and functions that are not in the OP's question.